# ksh + match and verify two strings in single line

Tags: linux, shell-scripting, ksh

how to match the words linux1a and linux1b from single line ? ( should be performed by ksh )

```
       list="solaris1a Auto global linux1a linux1b"


       echo $list | .... ?
```

my target is to find that linux1a  and linux1b are exists in the line { $list )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ echo $list | grep linux1a | grep linux1b
```

If after both the grep's you still get the output, then it exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
if [[ " $list " = *" linux1a "* && " $list " = *" linux1b "* ]]; then 
  echo yes
fi
```